# Expandablelistview Auto Expand - Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListview with Items. I want to automatically expand the group so I don't have to click it. Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use this [expandGroup(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup%28int%29) for this

```
yourListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
```

Comment: I only have one group in ExpandableListview

Comment: Then use yourListView.expandGroup(0);

Comment: private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
     HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","Updates"); // the key and it's value.
       
     result.add( m );
     
     
      }
      return (List)result;
    }